# Ionic Mapbox GeolocateControl: trackUserLocation?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, mapbox-gl-js

I can't figure out how to track the User Location via GPS.

This code can I add in my Mapbox:

```
const geolocate = (new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true
}));
map.addControl(geolocate)
```

But it doesn't show it in iOS. What to do? Maybe add some Ionic/Cordova tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

> Not all browsers support geolocation, and some users may disable the
>   feature. Geolocation support for modern browsers including Chrome
>   **requires sites to be served over HTTPS**. If geolocation support is not
>   available, the GeolocateControl will not be visible.

from:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#geolocatecontrol

Comment: It's visible, but not working because of Ionic I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the mapbox-gl css? Without the css files the markers and controls are invisible.

You might need to add this line in `angular.json`:

```
{
...
"projects": {
"app": {
  ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "styles": [
          ...
          },
          {
            "input": "node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css"
          }
```